# Confused about TestNG version# and Selenium-JAVA version# - How to get version number for Maven POM.xml file

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, pom.xml

I've Eclipse and TestNG.  I've played around with several projects using testng.xml.  Now I want to run the projects using POM.xml.  I've installed maven and created a new maven project.  After creating a script I opened my pom.xml file and copied a sample pom.xml file that I copied from online but unfortunately I received TestNG dependency error. I assumed the error was because of incorrect TestNG version.  So I went to Eclipse menu Help->About Eclipse IDE->Installation Details and got the version# of the TestNG that I'd installed.

TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration (Optional)   7.2.0.202004281604  org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group  TestNG Team

So I added the 7.2.0 to TestNG dependency to my Pom.xml but it's still showing error for TestNG dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
     <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
     <version>7.2.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

After some research I found this site https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng

1. My question is why does eclipse show that I installed 7.2.0 version of TestNG when there is no 7.2.0 TestNG version to begin with?   Anyhow version 7.3.0 finally worked.  I don't understand why did  version 7.3.0 work when I've 7.2.0 version installed on my machine.
2. My second question is how do I find out what my Selenium-Java version I've installed on  my machine?
   I've tried looking under Java Build Bath->Libraries tab and noticed that JRE System Library has JAVASE-13 and the Classpath is showing different version for different jar files.  For example
   byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar
   client-comined-3.141.59-srouces.jar
   commons-codec-1.13.jar
   Can someone please help me how do I go about finding out the correct selenium-java version?
   Shouldn't maven just download the version I add under dependency?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

["TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration"](https://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) is an Eclipse plugin for integrating with TestNG. You have version 7.2 of that plugin.

That's completely different from the actual TestNG library.

> Shouldn't maven just download the version I add under dependency?

Yes, it will download and use whatever you tell it to (provided it exists). Whether you have another version somewhere else on your computer is irrelevant.